# Calculating solar irradiance of Earth

Tags: radiation

The mean solar radiation flux absorbed per unit area of Earth’s surface, neglecting the atmosphere, is calculated as FS(1-A)/4, where FS is the solar constant and A is albedo. I can see how this would be valid for a sphere illuminated from all directions, but inasmuch as only half of the globe is illuminated at any given time, I would think that the correct calculation should be FS(1-A)/2. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, you are missing the geometry of a sphere.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $FS$ means the power per unit area then the power received by the earth is FS times the cross sectional area:

$$ P = FS\, \pi r^2 $$

The surface area of the earth is just the area of a sphere, $4\pi r^2$, so the average power per unit area of the Earth's surface is:

$$ P_\text{av} = \frac{FS\, \pi r^2}{4\pi r^2} = \frac{FS}{4} $$

Comment: My point is that the area illuminated is a hemisphere, not a sphere. Only half of Earth's surface is illuminated by sunlight at any given time. Shouldn't that make a difference?

Comment: @DavidLaing: I would guess the average you cite is the average over long periods i.e. times greater than one day. That means you average over both the day and night times.

Comment: Time is irrelevant. For this exercise, it really doesn't matter if Earth rotates or not. What does matter is that we are illuminating one half of a sphere, not the whole sphere. Because of this, it seems to me that the mean flux across the surface of the illuminated hemisphere should be FS(1-A)/2 rather than FS(1-A)/4.

Comment: It depends what you want to calculate. The average absorbed per unit area over the whole of the earth's surface is as John Rennie has said (give or take the albedo factor). The average absorbed by the illuminated half would indeed by $\frac{FS(1-A)}{2}$, and for the un-illuminated half it would be $0$. Which value you want depends on what exactly you want to use that value for.